# Proving the complexity of recursive determinant

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, determinants

I want to prove why Laplace determinant or recursive algorithm complexity is `n!`. Can anyone prove it for me? I don't know how could it then be `n!`, given that the equation `T(n)=nT(n-1)+3n-1` only involves multiplication and addition.

Comment: Great! Did you have a question?

Comment: Can you pls help me with it ?my equation is nearly hard to answer.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: The equation is  T(n)=nT(n-1)+3n-1 considering mults and pluses .how can i solve this because i dont know what to do with 3n-1 part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to expand:

```
T(n) = n T(n-1) + 3n-1 = 
       n ((n-1)T(n-2) + 3(n-1)-1) + 3n-1 =
       n (n-1) T(n-2) + 3 n (n-1)  - n + (3n - 1)
```

Now by induction you can show that (if `T(1) = 1`):

```
T(n) = n (n-1) (n-2) ... 1 + 3(n + n (n-1) + ... + n!) - 
      (1 + n + n (n-1) + ... + n (n-1) ... n * (n-1) * ... * (n-2)) 
     = Theta(n!)
```

Comment: I think your expanding is wrong there must be n^2 in the equation cause you cant take one out of paraethesis.

Comment: @Havoc there is! in `3 * n * (n+1) / 2`. However, it doesn't change the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: I think i got it why if you write the complete equation the last extra part will be something like n!(3n-(3n+1)) that its gonna remain n! .

Comment: @Havoc about the expansion you were right! The answer is updated, but the complexity is not changed.